# How to call Urls from custom html page in webview in android?

Tags: android

this is the content which i want to show in webview and after that i want to show specific href links on click in webview content??.please help me.

```
 {  "content": "<p>\n\t<img alt=\"rsz_shutterstock_317831516\" class=\"alignnone size-full wp-image-9200\" height=\"296\"
     src=\"http:\/\/rejsespejder.dk\/wp-content\/uploads\/2016\/05\/rsz_shutterstock_317831516.jpg\" width=\"783\" 
     srcset=\"http:\/\/rejsespejder.dk\/wp-content\/uploads\/2016\/05\/rsz_shutterstock_317831516.jpg 750w, 
     http:\/\/rejsespejder.dk\/wp-content\/uploads\/2016\/05\/rsz_shutterstock_317831516-300x114.jpg 300w\" 
     sizes=\"(max-width: 783px) 100vw, 783px\" \/>\n<\/p>\n<p>\n\tS&aring; g&aring;r turen til sol og varme p&aring; Cypern. Denne sp&aelig;ndende &oslash; med masser af historie, bjergtagende natur, fantastisk mad og ikke mindst l&aelig;kre strande, er meget forst&aring;elig et velbes&oslash;gt feriem&aring;l.<a class=\"more-link\"
     href=\"http:\/\/rejsespejder.dk\/lastminute-solsikre-cypern-1-uge-paa-laekkert-4-resort-kun-1-241-kr-inkl-fly\/\">  &#8230;<\/a><\/p>\n<div class=\"fcbk_share\"><div class=\"fcbk_like\">
     <fb:like href=\"http:\/\/rejsespejder.dk\/lastminute-solsikre-cypern-1-uge-paa-laekkert-4-resort-kun-1-241-kr-inkl-fly\/\" action=\"like\" 
     colorscheme=\"light\" layout=\"button_count\"  share=\"true\"><\/fb:like><\/div><\/div>",
 }
```

here is my webview activity

```
@SuppressLint("SetJavaScriptEnabled")
public class WebViewActivity extends Activity
{
     ProgressDialog progressDialog ;
    ImageView back;
    WebView web;
    String url,webcontent;
    boolean navigationtoLink=false;
    ArrayList<String> urllist=new ArrayList<String>();
      ProgressBar progressBar;
      RelativeLayout webrel;
      String url_web="https://online.adservicemedia.dk/cgi-bin/click.pl?cid=3501&amp;pid=7960&amp;deeplink=http%3A//www.trivago.dk/%3FiPathId%3D51462%26iGeoDistanceItem%3D42404%26aDateRange%255Barr%255D%3D2016-06-01%26aDateRange%255Bdep%255D%3D2016-06-12%26iRoomType%3D7%26cpt%3D4240402%252C199%26aHotelTestClassifier%3D%26aPriceRange%255Bto%255D%3D0%26aPriceRange%255Bfrom%255D%3D0%26iIncludeAll%3D0%26iGeoDistanceLimit%3D20000%26aPartner%3D%26iViewType%3D0%26bIsSeoPage%3Dfalse%26bIsSitemap%3Dfalse%26&amp;sub=RF Cancun";
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
     int GLOBAL_VAR_WIDTH = WebViewActivity.this.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getWidth();
     int width=GLOBAL_VAR_WIDTH/2;
        setContentView(R.layout.webview_activity);
        back=(ImageView) findViewById(R.id.back);
        web=(WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
        // progressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar1);
        Intent in =getIntent();
        //url=in.getStringExtra("url");
        webcontent=in.getStringExtra("content");
        webrel=(RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.webrel);
        System.out.println("content in webview" + webcontent);
        url="http://www.google.com";
        //web.postUrl(url, EncodingUtils.getBytes(webcontent, "base64"));

        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams accidentrel=(LayoutParams) webrel.getLayoutParams();
        accidentrel.width=GLOBAL_VAR_WIDTH;

       webrel.setLayoutParams(accidentrel);

        web.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);    
        web.getSettings().setAllowFileAccess(true);
        web.getSettings().setAllowContentAccess(true);
        web.getSettings().setSupportMultipleWindows(true);
        web.getSettings().supportMultipleWindows();       
        web.getSettings().setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);

        progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(WebViewActivity.this);
        progressDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
        progressDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        progressDialog.setCancelable(false);
        progressDialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
        progressDialog.show(); 

       web.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient()
       { 
           @Override
           public boolean onJsAlert(WebView view, String url, String message, JsResult result)
            { 
               if (!navigationtoLink) {
                   Document html = Jsoup.parse(webcontent);
                   Elements links = html.select("a[href]");
                   for (Element link : links) {

                       System.out.println("js alert 356333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333"+link.attr("href"));
                       if (link.attr("href").contains("https://online.adservicemedia.dk/cgi-bin/click.pl?cid=3501&amp;pid=7960&amp;deeplink=http%3A//www.trivago.dk/%3FiPathId%3D51462%26iGeoDistanceItem%3D42404%26aDateRange%255Barr%255D%3D2016-06-01%26aDateRange%255Bdep%255D%3D2016-06-12%26iRoomType%3D7%26cpt%3D4240402%252C199%26aHotelTestClassifier%3D%26aPriceRange%255Bto%255D%3D0%26aPriceRange%255Bfrom%255D%3D0%26iIncludeAll%3D0%26iGeoDistanceLimit%3D20000%26aPartner%3D%26iViewType%3D0%26bIsSeoPage%3Dfalse%26bIsSitemap%3Dfalse%26&amp;sub=RF Cancun")) { 

                           System.out.println("js alert 356333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333"+link.attr("href"));
                           view.loadUrl(link.attr("href"));
                       navigationtoLink=true;
                   }
                }
               }
            return navigationtoLink;
            }
           @Override
        public boolean onCreateWindow(WebView view, boolean isDialog, boolean isUserGesture, Message resultMsg) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
               Toast.makeText(WebViewActivity.this,"oncreate",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                   Document html = Jsoup.parse(webcontent);
                   Elements links = html.select("a[href]");
                 //  System.out.println("href" +links);
                   for (Element link : links) {
                       urllist.add(link.attr("href"));
                      // System.out.println("urllist"+urllist);
                   }
                      /*if (link.attr("href").contains("https://online.adservicemedia.dk/cgi-bin/click.pl?cid=3501&amp;pid=7960&amp;deeplink=http%3A//www.trivago.dk/%3FiPathId%3D447967%26iGeoDistanceItem%3D2381718%26aDateRange%255Barr%255D%3D2016-05-28%26aDateRange%255Bdep%255D%3D2016-06-04%26iRoomType%3D7%26cpt%3D238171802%26iViewType%3D0%26bIsSeoPage%3Dfalse%26bIsSitemap%3Dfalse%26&amp;sub=RF Rhodos")) { 
                      Toast.makeText(WebViewActivity.this, "oncreate"+link.attr("href") , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                           System.out.println("js alert 356333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333"+link.attr("href"));
                           view.loadUrl(link.attr("href"));*/
                   String web=view.getUrl();
                  // System.out.println("%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%"+web);
                   //System.out.println("%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@"+webcontent);
               // }
                   for (int i = 0; i <urllist.size(); i++) {
                      // System.out.println("@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@"+ links.attr("href"));
                      // String web=urllist.get(i);
                      // System.out.println("%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%"+web);
                       if (urllist.get(i).equals(links.attr("href"))) {
                          // Toast.makeText(WebViewActivity.this, urllist.get(i), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                           Toast.makeText(WebViewActivity.this,"oncreate in if",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                          view.loadUrl(urllist.get(i));
                    }
                      /*if (links.attr("href").equals(urllist.get(i))) {
                          Toast.makeText(WebViewActivity.this, urllist.get(i), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                          view.loadUrl(urllist.get(i));
                    }*/
                }

            return true;
        }

       });
        back.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                onBackPressed();
            }
        });     

        web.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient()
                {

                @Override
                public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap bitmap) {

                    super.onPageStarted(view, url, bitmap);
                }
                @Override
                public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                       Toast.makeText(WebViewActivity.this,"should" +url,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                       System.out.println("################## url" +url);

                       for (int i = 0; i <urllist.size(); i++) {

                         //  String web=view.getUrl();
                          // System.out.println("%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%"+web);
                          // System.out.println("%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@"+webcontent);
                           if (urllist.get(i).equals(url)) {
                              // Toast.makeText(WebViewActivity.this, urllist.get(i), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                             view.loadUrl(urllist.get(i));
                             return true;
                        }
                          /*if (links.attr("href").equals(urllist.get(i))) {
                              Toast.makeText(WebViewActivity.this, urllist.get(i), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                              view.loadUrl(urllist.get(i));
                        }*/
                    }
                          // System.out.println("js alert 356333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333"+link.attr("href"));
                           //Toast.makeText(WebViewActivity.this,"should" +link.attr("href"),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                      // String web=view.getOriginalUrl();
                     //  System.out.println("%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%##################"+web);
                  view.loadUrl(url);

                    return false;
                /*  if (url.contains("http://www.trivago.dk/?iPathId=106197&iGeoDistanceItem=2555930&aDateRange%5Barr%5D=2016-06-07&aDateRange%5Bdep%5D=2016-06-15&iRoomType=7&cpt=255593002&iViewType=0&bIsSeoPage=false&bIsSitemap=false&&id=115450&amp=&cip=45030087040101&cip_tc=7960")) {
                         Intent i = new
                         Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url)); 
                         startActivity(i);
                                 return true;
                    } else {
                            view.loadUrl(url);
                        return true;
                    }*/
                }

                @Override
                public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
                    progressDialog .dismiss();

                    super.onPageFinished(view, url);

                }
                });
         if(AppStatus.getInstance(WebViewActivity.this).isOnline()){   
                web.loadData(webcontent, "text/html", "UTF-8");

                }   else{
                    Toast.makeText(WebViewActivity.this,"No internet connectivity!!",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }

    }
    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
         if(web.canGoBack()) {
                web.goBack();
            } else {
                // Let the system handle the back button
                super.onBackPressed();
            }
         progressDialog .dismiss();
    }

       // web.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
    // web.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
    // web.getSettings().setLayoutAlgorithm(LayoutAlgorithm.SINGLE_COLUMN);
   //  web.setScrollBarStyle(WebView.SCROLLBARS_OUTSIDE_OVERLAY);
    // web.setScrollbarFadingEnabled(false);
     //web.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);         
     //sweb.getSettings().setSupportZoom(true); 
  // web.loadDataWithBaseURL(null,webcontent,"text/html", "UTF-8", null);
     // accidentrel.height=GLOBAL_VAR_HEIGHT/6;
     /*function stopScroll() 
        { document.ontouchmove = function(e){ e.preventDefault(); } } 
        function startScroll() { document.ontouchmove = function(e){ return true; } 
        }
        */
    //  myWebView.loadUrl("javascript:stopScroll()");

}
```

Comment: "content": "<p>\n\t<img alt=\"rsz_shutterstock_317831516\" class=\"alignnone size-full wp-image-9200\" height=\"296\" src=\"http:\/\/rejsespejder.dk\/wp-content\/uploads\/2016\/05\/rsz_shutterstock_317831516.jpg\" width=\"783\" srcset=\"http:\/\/rejsespejder.dk\/wp-content\/uploads\/2016\/05\/rsz_shutterstock_317831516.jpg 750w, http:\/\/rejsespejder.dk\/wp-

Comment: ccontent\/uploads\/2016\/05\/rsz_shutterstock_317831516-300x114.jpg 300w\" sizes=\"(max-width: 783px) 100vw, 783px\" \/>\n<\/p>\n<p>\n\tS&aring; g&aring;r turen til sol og varme p&aring; Cypern. Denne sp&aelig;ndende &oslash; med masser af historie, bjergtagende natur, fantastisk mad og ikke mindst l&aelig;kre strande, er meget forst&aring;elig et velbes&oslash;gt feriem&aring;l.

Comment: l.<a class=\"more-link\" href=\"http:\/\/rejsespejder.dk\/lastminute-solsikre-cypern-1-uge-paa-laekkert-4-resort-kun-1-241-kr-inkl-fly\/\">  &#8230;<\/a><\/p>\n<div class=\"fcbk_share\"><div class=\"fcbk_like\"><fb:like href=\"http:\/\/rejsespejder.dk\/lastminute-solsikre-cypern-1-uge-paa-laekkert-4-resort-kun-1-241-kr-inkl-fly\/\" action=\"like\" colorscheme=\"light\" layout=\"button_count\"  share=\"true\"><\/fb:like><\/div><\/div>",

Comment: above is my json content